# display messages from gmail in my website

Tags: php, gmail

I'm developing an e-commerce website, in the back-office I have a dashboard, in this dashboard I have a part where messages are displayed.

for now I'm using some messages records in the database, but I want to display messages from my gmail account in the dashboard of my back-office.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the [IMAP interface](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en) to GMail; there are native functions in PHP to deal with [IMAP connections](http://ca.php.net/imap), it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I am already downloading and showing the email from gmail using imap connection, the problem is some of the email are comming with different encoding.
If you need the code please see this URL
[How to fetch a gmail email and display it as it is shown in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759437/how-to-fetch-a-gmail-email-and-display-it-as-it-is-shown-in-gmail)